# phonegap app extremely slow to load website on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I have a phonegap app that opens a website using window.open(). While it works fine in testing, when I compile the app and install it on an iPhone using TestFlight it can take anywhere from 1 minute to 15 minutes to open the website. When it does everything works fine. The app store review is rejecting it because of the delay. What can I check to identify the cause of this delay?

Answer (score 0):

Use remote debugging with an iOS device (or a simulator). This will allow you to see error's log like debugging a web site.

See "Safari in iOS" in : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

- Open the Settings app.
- Tap Safari.
- Scroll down and select Advanced.
- Switch Web Inspector to ON.
- After Web Inspector is enabled, connect your device to your desktop machine with a USB cable. The name of your device appears in the Develop menu of Safari.

Also, depending of what you want to do, I suggest you, instead of using window.open, to use the [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) plugin to open link in the browser (outside the webview of Cordova/Phonegap)